# Is there a way to get a line number for an Oracle error using Excel?

Tags: sql, vba, oracle, oledb, adodb

I do lots of Oracle SQL queries using Microsoft Excel.  The connection to Oracle is made via VBA using an ADODB.Connection object and a connection string with Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.  It works very well.  However, sometimes when constructing a new query, I make an error.  I'm wondering if there is a way to extract more information (such as the line number) from the Oracle error message that is passed to VBA.

Example; this is a working query that gives me valid results:

```
SELECT owner, table_name, column_name 
FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE upper(column_name) LIKE  '%FRAME%'
```

Now, let's introduce an error by forgetting the closing parenthesis for the UPPER() function in line 3:

```
SELECT owner, table_name, column_name 
FROM all_tab_columns 
WHERE upper(column_name LIKE  '%FRAME%'
```

If I run this query in Oracle SQL Developer, I get the following error message:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 25
```

If I run the same query in the more basic Oracle SQL*Plus terminal, I also get the line number and a visual indicator of where the error has occurred:

```
WHERE upper(column_name LIKE  '%FRAME%'
                        *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

However, in Excel, all I get is the basic Oracle error statement (ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis), without any indication of where the error is in my query.
[(Excel VBA Run-time Error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LnnK.png)

For this example, it's easy enough to find, but for some complex queries, it can be tricky to find the location of the error.

Is there any way to get additional information such as the line number from the error message that is thrown by the ADODB Open method or OraOLEDB.Oracle provider?

Sample VBA Code:

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cnStr As String
Dim qry As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
cnStr = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;" _
      & "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(CID=GTU_APP)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=redacted)(PORT=1234)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=redacted)(SERVER=DEDICATED)));" _
      & "User Id=redacted;" _
      & "Password=redacted;"
qry = "SELECT owner, table_name, column_name " _
    & "FROM all_tab_columns " _
    & "WHERE upper(column_name LIKE '%FRAME%'"
cn.Open cnStr
rs.Open qry, cn
```

(The qry statement is not actually hard-coded in VBA; I read it from a worksheet, but this would give the same result.)

If there is an error in the SQL query statement, the run-time error will occur on the last line when attempting to open the RecordSet.

Comment: Might help t show some of your actual code around how you're getting the current error message.  Are you looking at the Connections `Errors` property after catching the run-time error?  I don't know if that would give you more info than you're already getting.

Comment: Right now I have no error-handling.  I just let Excel throw the run-time error.  I'll take a look at the Errors property as suggested.

Comment: I'm sure that one limitation of this method is that I don't actually have "lines" in my query (unlike the Oracle SQL Developer or SQL*Plus applications).  The qry statement is just one long string.  However, it would still be helpful to have some indication of _where_ in that string Oracle found the error.

Comment: If you have SQL Developer and/or SQL*Plus, why wouldn't you first create query there and - once it is OK - copy it to Excel? Or, at least, go to any "Online SQL formatter" and format query you write? It'll fail to format it if it is invalid.

Comment: I like to use Excel for my SQL queries, because I typically want the results in an Excel spreadsheet.  I don't want to open additional applications and add additional steps if I don't have to.  The spreadsheet I use for SQL queries is intended for a wider audience than just me; many of them won't have SQL Developer or know how to use it, but they know how to use Excel.  Thanks for the online SQL formatter suggestion!  I tried several, and several did not catch the missing parentheses in the example above.

Comment: So far, nothing in the Err object or Connection.Errors collection exposes the position or context of the error in the SQL query.  I'm guessing that the OraOLEDB provider does not include this information.

Answer (score 0):

Te UPPER Function requires closing brackets. So...

```
WHERE upper(column_name) LIKE '%FRAME%'
```